# Visual Studio Code, CMake cannot find third party library headers even if the CMakeList.txt is correct

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

I want to use the `ranges-v3` library for my c++ project inside Visual Studio Code, since the `CLion IDE` crashes or has performance issues with larger projects.

I downloaded the `C++ Plugin` by Microsoft and the `CMake-tools` and `CMake` plugin to work with CMake. Additionally, I changed my `c_cpp_properties.json`, so it uses my g++ compiler (GCC 9.2) and copied parts of my cmake code into my new `CMakeLists.txt` to use the ranges library.

My problem is, that the ranges library headers are not found in my vscode project, but in my CLion project it works fine using the `add_library`, `set_target_properties` and `target_link_libraries` functions.

The error message that is thrown when I write `#include <range/v3/view/iota.hpp>` is the following:

```
fatal error: range/v3/view/iota.hpp: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <range/v3/view/iota.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Here my JSON and CMake code.
c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/local/bin/g++",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++20",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "vector-of-bool.cmake-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(Tensor_Lib VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_library(range_v3 INTERFACE IMPORTED) #same code in CLION CMakeLists.txt
set_target_properties(range_v3 PROPERTIES
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES /home/name/Libraries/range-v3/range-v3-master/include) #same code in CLION CMakeLists.txt

add_compile_options(-fconcepts) #enables concepts(unstable). Stable versions will be released with gcc/g++ 10

add_executable(Tensor_Lib main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Tensor_Lib range_v3) #same code in CLION CMakeLists.txt


set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

Another CMakeList.txt version that doesn't work:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)

project(Tensor_Lib VERSION 0.0.1)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

set(RANGES_DIRECTORY /home/name/Libraries/range-v3/range-v3-master/include)

set(HEADER_FILES ${RANGES_DIRECTORY}/range/v3/view/iota.hpp)

add_executable(Tensor_Lib main.cpp ${HEADER_FILES})

target_include_directories(Tensor_Lib INTERFACE ${RANGES_DIRECTORY})


set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

Comment: Use [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) to add the directory to the executable target.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i added the code `target_include_directories(Tensor_Lib /home/name/Libraries/range-v3/range-v3-master/include)` after my add_executable and comment-out my old code, but unfortunately, it still doesn't work.

Comment: You need the library **and** the include directory.

Comment: @sweenish i updated my code. I am adding the header files i want to use to my exe but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You need to specify `PUBLIC` or `PRIVATE` scope, not `INTERFACE`.

Comment: i thank you very much, now it works.